# service command not found

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to start ssh using:

```
service sshd start
```

but the service command can't be found, so it gives me an error:

```
zsh: command not found: service
```

What should I do?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Can't help much because I use Bash. But here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428374/commands-not-found-on-zsh is a question identical to yours about common applications path pointing in the wrong direction.

Comment: Check your `PATH` variable.  The `service` command for me is located in `/usr/sbin/service` so make sure `/usr/sbin` is added to your `PATH`

Comment: I see you got it.  Don't mind if I post it as an answer ? Also , FYI for the future, after you edit `.zshrc` file or `.bashrc` ( for bash )  file use `source` command ( or if that's `dash` or `ksh` shell , use `.` ) . For example, `source ~/.bashrc` That will reload the configuration

Comment: @Unique Since this is a Q&A site, all answers are expected to be in answer section only. Considering this, I have rolled back your edit. Moreover, it seems you found Sergiy comment and answer helpful. You might consider marking their answer as [accepted](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 9):

`command not found` typically results from 2 cases:

1. an executable not having execute permissions for your user or group
2. an executable not belonging to a folder listed in `PATH` variable , or the opposite - `PATH` variable that does not contain the location of your executable.

As have been solved in the comments , your case is #2.   For future readers, the solution is as such:

1. open your shell's configuration file in any text editor. If your shell is `bash` open `~/.bashrc` , if your shell is `zsh` open `~/.zshrc`. Note that `~` refers to your home directory.
2. Add line `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin"` . Note, that `/usr/sbin` is just an example, your location might be different.
3. Save the file, exit and run `source ~/.zshrc` or `source ~/.bashrc`. Note, that for shells such as `ksh` or `dash` you will need to use `. ~/.bashrc` since `source` command is `bashism` and is not portable

Answer (score 1):

I restarted docker using `systemctl` in place of `service`.

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: And what happened next, ie why did you do so?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
sudo find / -type f -iname service
```

if you get */sbin/service* then

```
/sbin/service sshd start
```